# Copy the screen time data

Tags: system-settings, shortcuts-app

In order to copy the screen time data and paste it to spreadsheet, what would be the easiest way possible?

Currently, I have created a shortcut to extract text from screenshot and then I need to scroll down in ‘system preferences -> screen time’, and then paste the data in spreadsheet, then I need to repeat this task till all the items are scrolled.

Is there an easier way to achieve this?